# Use same random number in Javascript AND php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parsing

I want to generate a random number between 1 and 10, use it in Javascript to return a random item in that array, and use that SAME item in PHP. Thus, I create a random number:

```
var iRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

I use that number in my Javascript function, and then I have my PHP like this:

```
$json_a['items'][$iRandomPHP]['title']
```

**Simply said, the `$iRandomPHP` must have the same random number as in my javascript variable iRandom.** I tried jquery .post like this:

```
$.post('custom_search.php', {iRandomPHP: iRandomPHP});
```

Trying to convert it in PHP like this:

```
$iRandomPHP = $_POST['iRandomPHP'];
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

For some more complete code:

```
<script>
    var iRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $.post('custom_search.php', {iRandomPHP: iRandom});
    function hndlr(response) {
        var item = response.items[iRandom];
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += item.title + "<br>" + "<img src=" + item.link + ">";
    }
</script>
```

PHP code:

```
        $iRandomPHP = $_POST['iRandomPHP']."haha";
        print_r($iRandomPHP);

        $url_nocb = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=".$key."&cx=013263683795763287108:ne-fxf3oy-a&searchType=image&q=office";
        $json_string = file_get_contents($url_nocb);
        $json_a = json_decode($json_string, true);
        print $json_a['items'][$iRandomPHP]['title']."<br>";
```

That's all

Comment: You define `iRandom` in javascript but try to send it as `iRandomPHP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$.post('custom_search.php', {iRandomPHP: iRandomPHP});
```

should read

```
$.post('custom_search.php', {iRandomPHP: iRandom});
```

since you are passing the js var `iRandom`

Comment: I tried that as well, but it doesn't return anything :(

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't return anything? have you tried any debugging at all? need some more info on how it's "not working" to help

Comment: Sorry, I have little knowledge about this or debugging. I use this to look for debugging:

`$iRandomPHP = $_POST['iRandomPHP']."haha";
   print_r($iRandomPHP);`

It doe return "haha", but not the number. I assume it's not returning anything that way?